# new dynamic feature modules & hotswapping

Tags: android, module, hotswap

Can the new android dynamic feature modules

- https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/configure

potentially be used for releasing an update of some dex files / features in production without forcing the user to upgrade the application through the playstore?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question yet ?

Comment: not yet unfortunately. i want to try myself, but didn't have time this month. if i manage to play a little bit more with bundles and discover the answer, i'll post it

Comment: Can you help me with this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64191100/using-dynamic-feature-module-fonts-downloaded-and-installed-in-asset-folder-but

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this can't be used for this purpose.

However we (Google) are working on an **In-App Update API** so you can trigger an update of your app from within your app, so the user doesn't have to leave your app to get the newer version. See https://youtu.be/QdoEcfibG-s?t=1762